# ul bullets not aligning

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to use

```html
<ul style="text-align:center">

  <li> 1794 - born in Berkeley, UK </li>
  <li> 1821 - began his training as a doctor </li>

</ul>
```

Unfortunately, neither bullets and text align correctly, I've tried using divs and it still doesn't work.

This is what is happening:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: you're aligning it to the center, so that is what it should look like.  How do you want to align it? center, left?

Comment: Your image is what I'd expect for center alignment. The text align is horizontal.

Comment: I want it to be centered, but I need the bullets (the dots before text, I don't know if that's the right word) to be on top of each other, but they aren't aligned vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple code snippet

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">1794 - born in Berkeley, UK</li>
  <li class="list-item">1821 - began his training as a doctor</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfect! No problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the list centered in the page/parent element, but have the list items aligned to the left, wrap the ul tag in a block container that has a `text-align: center;`, and set the ul as a `display: inline-block;` and `text-align: left;`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WdyVPJ

Code
HTML

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">1794 - born in Berkeley, UK</li>
  <li class="list-item">1821 - began his training as a doctor</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
  text-align: left;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I want the bullets to the on top of each other, but they don't seem to allign vertically.

Comment: That might be it, is there any way for me to verify it though? Or do I have to trust my guts that it is alligned everytime?

Comment: you could buy a bigger monitor, you could use mediaQueries to scale down... there's a lot of things you can do it...

Answer (score -1):

That's because you have to center the internal elements (`<li>`) while aligning to the left the external element (`<ul>`)

```
<ul style="text-align:left">
    <li style="text-align:center"> 1794 - born in Berkeley, UK </li>
    <li style="text-align:center"> 1821 - began his training as a doctor </li>
</ul>
```

Check the result here: https://jsfiddle.net/L1xmkof6/

Comment: Sorry, I might have expressed myself wrong, I want the bullets to allign vertically, having the text expand to the right if it gets too big.